# How to Remove QueryString Values to Avoid Tombstoning Issues

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to test the Lens application feature, in which my app is supposed to navigate directly to `CameraCaptureTask` after a user selects the app from the LensPicker (since I do not have a viewfinder on my MainPage). Upon returning to MainPage, the `CamerCaptureTask` has a completed event which will display the image on the screen.

I am having an issue with a weird recurring situation where my `CameraCaptureTask` is repeatedly called based on the result of a `QueryString` value that I cannot clear before the application is tombstoned and then restarted after `CameraCaptureTask` completes.

LensExampleUriMapper.cs

```
private string tempUri;

public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
    tempUri = uri.ToString();

    // Look for a URI from the lens picker.
    if (tempUri.Contains("ViewfinderLaunch"))
    {
        // Launch as a lens, launch viewfinder screen.
        return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?fromLensPicker=" + "fromLensPicker", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    // Otherwise perform normal launch.
    return uri;
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string fromLensPicker = null;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("fromLensPicker", out fromLensPicker))
    {
        if (fromLensPicker == "fromLensPicker")
        {
            newButton_Click(null, null);  //click event that calls CameraCaptureTask
            fromLensPicker = null; //Temporarily nullifies value until MainPage is OnNavigatedTo after CameraCaptureTask completes
        }
    }
}
```

How might I clear the `QueryString` value so my application does not continuously call `newButton_Click(null, null)` after `CameraCaptureTask` completes and the app is continued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string fromLensPicker = null;
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("fromLensPicker", out fromLensPicker))
{
    if (fromLensPicker == "fromLensPicker")
    {
        NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("fromLensPicker");
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OnNavigatedTo of MainPage use NavigationMode to find if you are returning from CameraCaptureTask

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
         return;

     // else continue further with CameraCaptureTask
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
         // continue further with CameraCaptureTask
}
```